# Android Status bar notification every day at time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

In my app, users have to fill in 9 different times with timepickers. These times are stored in a SQLite database. I want that users get a status bar notification when one of the times has been reached.

Example:

Users fill the first time in at 09:00.
If it is 09:00 in real time, users need to get a statusbar notification. I want that they don't need to start the app, it has to be automatic.

After spending more then 4 hours today at stackoverflow and other websites, I didn't succeed. I have tried the following code, but I didn't succeed. The notification is now set to 12:00. When the time reached 12:00, I didn't get a message.

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
AlarmManager am;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent); } }
```

TimeAlarm.class:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

 NotificationManager nm;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);

 }
}
```

NotificationService.class:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    handleIntent(intent);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private NotificationManager nm;
private WakeLock mWakeLock;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mWakeLock.release();
}

private void showNotification() {


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("Test message");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}

private class PollTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        showNotification();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        stopSelf();
    }
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "NotificationsService");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (!cm.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
        stopSelf();
        return;
    }
    new PollTask().execute();
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.test.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.test.app.TimeAlarm">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing START_NOT_STICKY to START_STICKY;. If your service isn't sticky android does not try to restart it if it has to be killed to make room for other apps in memory.

Comment: Ah, thanks, but it didn't work, unfortunately. Do you have an example for my question? With the code I posted it doesn't work. So I need a statusbar notification when the real time is matching the saved time, repeating every day except the weekend.